# how can text be wrapped in columns using gawk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to wrap columns of text using gawk or native bash, The fourth column (last one in this case) wraps to the next line. I would like it to wrap and all text remain under the respective heading. The output for the given input is just representative and text needing wrapped is in the last column. However id like to wrap ANY column

I have tried embedding fmt and fold commands in the awk script  but have been unsuccessful in getting results required.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; format="%-35s %-7s %-5s %-20s\n"
printf "\n"
printf format, "Date", "Task ID", "Code", "Description"
printf format ,"-------------------------", "-------", "-----", "------------------------------"}
{printf format, strftime("%c",$1), $2, $3, $4}'
```

INPUT:
1563685965|878|12015|Task HMI starting
1563686011|881|5041|Configured with engine 6000.8403 (/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/engine/lib/liblnxfv.so), dats 9322.0000 (/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/engine/dat), 197 extensions, 0 extra drivers
1563686011|882|5059|Created Scanner child id=1 pid=28,698 engine=6000.8403, dats=9322.0000
1563686139|883|12017|Task HMI Completed 2 items detected in 19 files (0 files timed out, 0 files excluded, 0 files cleaned, 0 files had errors, 0 were not scanned)
1563686139|885|5012|scanned=19 excluded=0 infected=2 cleaned=0 cleanAttempts=0 cleanRequests=0 denied=0 repaired=0 deleted=0 renamed=0 quarantined=0 timeouts=0 errors=0 uptime=174 busy=0 wait=0

I am still unclear on how to post or share on formation on this forum. This seems to work fairly well. The wrap function was taken from the duplicate post.

BEGIN{ 
            format="%-35s %-7s %-10s %-20s\n"
            printf "\n"
            printf format, "Date", "Task ID", "Code", "Description"
            printf format ,"-------------------------", "-------", "-----", "------------------------------"
        }

```
    {
        split($0,cols,"|")

        numLines=1

        for(col in cols){

            numLines=wrap(cols[col],80,colArr)

            for(c in colArr){
                fmtcol[col,c] = colArr[c]       
            }

            maxLinesRow[col]=(numLines > maxLinesRow[col] ? numLines : maxLinesRow[col])
        }    

        for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=maxLinesRow[col]; lineNr++) {
            dt=((1,lineNr) in fmtcol ? strftime("%c",fmtcol[1,lineNr]):"")
            printf format, dt, fmtcol[2,lineNr], fmtcol[3,lineNr], fmtcol[4,lineNr]
        }
        printf "\n"
        delete colArr
    }

function wrap(inStr,wid,outArr,         lineEnd,numLines) {
    while ( length(inStr) > wid ) {
        lineEnd = ( match(substr(inStr,1,wid),/.*[[:space:]]/) ? RLENGTH - 1 : wid )
        outArr[++numLines] = substr(inStr,1,lineEnd)
        inStr = substr(inStr,lineEnd+1)
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",inStr)
    }
    outArr[++numLines] = inStr
    return numLines
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample input text and what you want the result to look like?

Comment: I am new to this site so I am having trouble posting desired output. Generically I’d like to wrap text under its column heading using a width that would likely be longer than the column width defined in the printf format.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you're using gawk, but tabular formatting with line wrapping like you want is really easy to do with perl, so here's a perl solution using the [format](https://perldoc.pl/perlform) feature's repeated fill mode:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

printf "%-40s %-20s\n", 'Date', 'Description';
print '-' x 40, ' ', '-' x 20, "\n";

my ($date, $desc);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    ($date, $desc) = split '\|', $_;
    $date = strftime '%c', localtime($date);
    write;
}

format STDOUT =
^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ~~
$date,                                   $desc
.
```

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
1000|this is some text
2000|this is some other text that is long enough that it will wrap around a bit.
$ perl fmt.pl input.txt
Date                                     Description
---------------------------------------- --------------------
Wed, Dec 31, 1969  4:16:40 PM            this is some text
Wed, Dec 31, 1969  4:33:20 PM            this is some other
                                         text that is long
                                         enough that it will
                                         wrap around a bit.
```

Comment: This is  a nice solution. Unfortunately this needs to be addressed using gawk as it is one of the requirements for this particular project.